# Slick slider issue: Image not showing on initial load

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, slick.js

When I run the slider, the initial image is not being displayed. Only after I click on the 'next' button does the slider start to function.

Link to issue: http://zaaroinfotechsolutions.com/zaarodemo/longbeach/corporate/ (click on the history tab and scroll all the way down)

Here is my code:
**html**

```
<div class="col-sm-9" style="padding:0px;"> <div class="main-slick">
                        <?php 
                               $args = array(
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'post_type' => 'slide',
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                          'taxonomy' => 'slide_category',
                                          'field'    => 'slug',
                                          'terms'    => 'history'
                                        )
                                    )
                                  );
                                  $query = new WP_Query($args);

                                   while ($query->have_posts()) :
                                    $query->the_post();
                                    $feat_image_main = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));

                                ?>
          <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));          ?>" class="img-responsive mainimage" id="mainimage">
<?php endwhile; ?> </div> </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.main-slick').slick( { infinite: false});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually refresh the positioning of the Slick plugin after the history tab is visible. Add this to your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.main-slick').slick('setPosition');
  });
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VNZidqA11TKdXMNX58tP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me on the initial visit, then the problem occurred next visit. I suspect a cache error?

Comment: Yes I realised that too! Any idea on the cause?

Answer (score 0):

in my project `slick('setPosition')` didn't worked but the above code with `slick('refresh')` worked so I used:
`$('.main-slick').slick('refresh');`